# C Turning a dynamic char array into an array of char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a function, that has to take a dynamic char array, separate it at spaces, and put each word in an array of char arrays. Here's the code:

```
char** parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline)
{
    char** arguments = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char* buffer;
    int lineCount = 0, strCount = 0, argCount = 0;
    int spaceBegin = 0;
    while((cmdline[lineCount] != '\n'))
    {
        if(cmdline[lineCount] == ' ')
        {
            argCount++;
            arguments[argCount] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            strCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = realloc(arguments[argCount], strCount + 1);
            arguments[argCount] = buffer;
            arguments[argCount][strCount] = cmdline[lineCount];
            strCount++;
        }
        lineCount++;
    }
    arguments[argCount] = '\0';
    free(buffer);
    return arguments;   
}
```

The problem is that somewhere along the way I get a Segmentation fault and I don't exacly know where. 
Also, this current version of the function assumes that the string does not begin with a space, that is for the next version, i can handle that, but i can't find the reason for the seg. fault

Comment: `char *` and `char **` are not an arrays! A pointer is not an array!

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where. And do not cast `malloc()` to the target pointer type. Read the frequents tab for [tag:c], the first question.

Comment: Also, `malloc(sizeof(char))` will only allocate a single byte.

Comment: @Olaf Although a pointer isn't an array, it can be used as an array if it is malloced with enough space. (The pointer arithmetic can be done using brackets which is what I think the person is trying to do, i "believe").

Comment: @JonathanSmit: You refer to the subscription operator, I assume. That is just because an array _decays_ to a pointer for most cases, including this operator. And even when it points to a sequence of variables of the same type, a pointer is not an array. Try `sizeof(char *)` or `char * = `&(char [4])` (type-expressions). And a `char **` is still not an "array of arrays". Also, the title is very missleading. It implies to convert/cast types, while the question actually is about processing data from one array and store the results into another.

Comment: O! I see now, thanks for clarifying those things for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is surely not what you intended:

```
char** arguments = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

It allocates a block of memory large enough for one `char`, and sets a variable of type `char **` (`arguments`) to point to it.  But even if you wanted only enough space in `arguments` for a single `char *`, what you have allocated is not enough (not on any C system you're likely to meet, anyway).  It is certainly not long enough for multiple pointers.

Supposing that pointers are indeed wider than single `char`s on your C system, your program invokes undefined behavior as soon as it dereferences `arguments`.  A segmentation fault is one of the more likely results.

The simplest way forward is probably to scan the input string twice: once to count the number of individual arguments there are, so that you can allocate enough space for the pointers, and again to create the individual argument strings and record pointers to them in your array.

Note, too, that the return value does not carry any accessible information about how much space was allocated, or, therefore, how many argument strings you extracted.  The usual approach to this kind of problem is to allocate space for one additional pointer, and to set that last pointer to `NULL` as a sentinel.  This is much akin to, but not the same as, using a null *`char`* to mark the end of a C string.

**Edited to add:**

The allocation you want for `arguments` is something more like this:

```
arguments = malloc(sizeof(*arguments) * (argument_count + 1));
```

That is, allocate space for one more object than there are arguments, with each object the size of the type of thing that `arguments` is intended to point at.  The value of `arguments` is not accessed by `sizeof`, so it doesn't matter that it is indeterminate at that point.

**Edited to add:**

The `free()` call at the end is also problematic:

```
free(buffer);
```

At that point, variable `buffer` points to the same allocated block as the last element of `arguments` points to (or is intended to point to).  If you free it then *all* pointers to that memory are invalidated, including the one you are about to return to the caller.  You don't need to free `buffer` at that point any more than you needed to free it after any of the other allocations.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably why you have a segmentation fault:

In `char** arguments = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char));`, you have used `malloc (sizeof (char))`, this allocates space for only a single byte (enough space for one `char`). This is not enough to hold a single `char*` in `arguments`.

But even if it was in some system, so `arguments[argCount]` is only reading allocated memory for `argCount = 0`. For other values of `argCount`, the array index is out of bounds - leading to a segmentation fault.

For example, if your input string is something like this - `"Hi. How are you doing?"`, then it has `4 ' '` characters before `\n` is reached, and the value of `argCount` will go up till `3`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is somthing like this:

```
char** parse_cmdline( const char *cmdline )
{
```

Allocate your array of argument pointers with length for 1 pointer and init it with 0.

```
char** arguments = malloc( sizeof(char*) );
arguments[0] = NULL;
```

Set a `char*` pointer to the first `char` in yor command line and remember the
beginn of the first argument

```
int argCount = 0, len = 0;
const char *argStart = cmdline;
const char *actPos = argStart;
```

Continue until end of command line reached.
If you find a blank you have a new argument which consist of th characters between `argStart` and `actPos` . Allocate and copy argument from command line.

```
while( *actPos != '\n' && *actPos != '\0' )
{
    if( cmdline[lineCount] == ' ' && actPos > argStart )
    {
        argCount++; // increment number of arguments
        arguments = realloc( arguments, (argCount+1) * sizeof(char*) ); // allocate argCount + 1 (NULL at end of list of arguments)
        arguments[argCount] = NULL; // list of arguments ends with NULL
        len = actPos - argStart;
        arguments[argCount-1] = malloc( len+1 ); // allocate number of characters + '\0'
        memcpy( arguments[argCount-1], actPos, len ); // copy characters of argument
        arguments[argCount-1] = 0; // set '\0' at end of argument string
        argStart = actPos + 1; // next argument starts after blank
    }
    actPos++;
}
return arguments;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions i would give is, before calling malloc, you might want to first count the number of words you have. then call malloc as `char ** charArray = malloc(arguments*sizeof(char*));`. This will be the space for the char ** charArray. Then each element in charArray should be malloced by the size of the word you are trying to store in that element. Then you may store that word inside that index. 
Ex. `*charArray = malloc(sizeof(word));` Then you can store it as `**charArray = word;`

Be careful with pointer arithmetic however.

The segmentation fault is definitly arising from you trying to access an element in an array in an undefined space. Which arises from you not mallocing space correctly for the array.